# Convergence in $\ell^2$ and $\ell^{\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let X be the set of all absolutely convergent sequences, i.e. $$X = \{(a_n)_n: \sum_{i=0}^\infty |a_n| <\infty  \} $$
I want to find a sequence $(x_n)_n$ where $x_n \in X$ for all $n$ and $x_n\to x$ in $\ell^\infty$ but $x_n\nrightarrow x$ in $\ell^2$ (where $x \in X)$.

Can anyone help? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_n$ be the sequence

$$(1/\sqrt n, 1/\sqrt n, \dots, 1/\sqrt n,0,0,0\dots ),$$

where there are $n$ entries of $1/\sqrt n$ in the first $n$ slots. Then each $x_n\in X,$ $x_n \to 0$ in $l^\infty,$ but $x_n$ does not converge to $0$ in $l^2.$

Comment: Thank you. I understood the sequence goes to $0$  in $l^\infty$ but not in $l^2$. But is $x_n\in X $ for all $n?$ Because $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |x_n| = \frac{1}{\sqrt n}\cdot n =\sqrt n  $ goes to $\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. Are all terms absolutely convergent? (are all terms in X?) Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Yes, you might be misunderstanding something. Isn't it clear that $x_n \in X$ for all $n$?

Comment: When I think about $x_n$ for an arbitrary $n$ then I understand $x_n\in X$. But because $(x_n)_n$ is a sequence when I think about the situation when $n\to\infty$ I think $x_n$ does not belong $X$ anymore because $\sqrt n \to\infty$.

Comment: What I understand is $x_n$ belongs to $l^\infty$ as $n\to\infty$ but does not belong to $l^1$. (Here, I mean $l^\infty = \{(a_n)_n: sup |a_n| <\infty  \}$ and $l^1 = X$.) I don't quite get how $x_n\in X $ for all $n$

Comment: You are having difficulty with a basic idea: any sequence that equals $0$ except in finitely many slots is in $X!$

Comment: I understand now! Thank you so much!!